# Which replacement method is called when editing an attributed string?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsmutableattributedstring, textkit, nstextstorage

[`NSMutableAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring) defines two string replacement methods:

```
func replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, 
                       with str: String)
```

and

```
func replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, 
                with attrString: NSAttributedString)
```

I have created a subclass of `NSTextStorage` which in its turn is a subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString`. In that subclass I overrode both of the above methods.

To my surprise, the latter method (which passes an attributed replacement string) is never called when I type or paste something in my text view. It's only the plain string replacement method that gets called each time.

This leads me to the question:
**Based on which rules are these two methods actually called**, when the user is editing the text in a text view?

(I need to perform different operations in my text storage, depending on whether the attributed replacement string contains a specific kind of text attachment. But if the replacement method for the attributed string is never called, I see no way how to make this distinction. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function

```
func replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, 
                with attrString: NSAttributedString)
```

is actually never called.

From documentation (below) it is clear that one should use combination of  `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` followed by a call `setAttributes:range:`

> /* Note for subclassing NSTextStorage: NSTextStorage is a
>   semi-abstract subclass of NSMutableAttributedString. It implements
>   change management (beginEditing/endEditing), verification of
>   attributes, delegate handling, and layout management notification. The
>   one aspect it does not implement is the actual attributed string
>   storage --- this is left up to the subclassers, which need to override
>   the two NSMutableAttributedString primitives in addition to two
>   NSAttributedString primitives:
>
> - (NSString *)string;
> - (NSDictionary *)attributesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)location effectiveRange:(NSRangePointer)range;
> - (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)str;
> - (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs range:(NSRange)range;    These primitives should perform the change then call
>     edited:range:changeInLength: to get everything else to happen.
>     */

Make sure you have custom implementation of these methods.

And this is also how AppKit implements `NSTextView`:

[image]